# How to count the number of times a non-registered User presses "Search", then save it in MySQL database and limit that number for every user?

Tags: php, jquery, html, web-applications

So I'm working on a website which brings up movie/tv-show posters on clicking "search". Now I'm wondering how can I limit the search button for non-users to 10-15 searches and have unlimited searches for registered users. Think of it like a premium membership sorta deal where the people who pay, get the extra-clicks and people who're using the trial product, get only 10 clicks. What I want to ask is, how do I log the number of times a non-registered user uses the search engine and how do I put a cap on it? And remove that cap for registered users.So please let me know where I can start from.

Comment: if the user registered then use his data from the session and if not then store clicks in session and check in every click you fix clicks count Or you can store the user's public IP address as @Daan said

Comment: @M.Hemant That's not a good approach, the unregistered user could than just close the browser and search again. Better to store the user's public IP address.

Comment: since user is not registered, you can store the ip in db to identify user and then count number of clicks on search button and reasonn accordingly

Comment: You can try to fingerprint unregistered users and limit them this way, but that isn't accurate always. The simplest fingerprint is IP, but many users can be using the same IP so you would need to have a better fingerprint algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow this awesome I usually find app that limits visitors but after they make free account then they reach the limit after that they should pay to have premium account without limits

But any way that can be achieved easy I will explain without codes cause it needs long run

First you should create function to retrieve users 
IP address so you may use  remote_addr or http_forward in case of you use proxy

Second go to database and create table called 
Ip_users or whatever you need   This table should have 2  column. Ip column and id_hash column now you should set ip_column as varchar and id_hash as init

Third is most easy step make Ajax script that take the ip value that we get above in first step and send it to .php script call it  uservalid.php as example

Fourth. Uservalid.php should first select count of records for ip if it null it make insert for new ip if it more than zero it update ip_hash + 1   If ip_hash equals 10 it make redirect to account page

This why you need index on IP address column and this is general steps

Maybe free account as start with limits then premium account is better

Comment: This should be it. Thank you for walking me through the process so nicely.

Comment: You should thank stack overflow because when I submit the answer I encountered error that this question is out then I leave the page without further submissions the admin review the Q&A and repost my answer . Good project

Answer (score 0):

cheking the number of clicks of each ip adress is not bad idea but it wont solve the problem beacause if the user restart the modem he ll get new ip adress.
in my opinion, you can make all users need an account to use the search option and do your check according to that, if the user want to search more than 10-15 searches he/she need to get premium account.